# Do Google Map Placemark Clusters always load all placemarks before clustering?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I apologize if the question is simplistic, or if this is not the correct place to post this. Just not sure where else to go.

We are having a company develop a photography website for us, which will also include a worldwide map of the image locations, with clickable placemarks. Because there are thousands of photos, it makes sense to have the map “cluster” placemarks, especially when zoomed out at global, continental and state levels — becoming individual markers the closer you zoom in. The developer has indicated that, due to a google limitation, the individual markers ALL load first, THEN cluster into sections. Which is problematic in that it slows the site down (each placemark has a thumbnail image).

Is there not a current solution out there that would just show cluster representations first, then only “load” placemarks the closer you get?  Seems there must be a way that loading of placemarks should only be happening at zoomed-in levels anyway.

If all markers DO have to load initially, then we probably need to figure out how to only load certain regions at a time, to cut down on website load time.  Is there a way to assign clusters to regions? At this point, the developer has the clusters and markers coded to their countries, but we like the idea of letting them cluster due to locations in general or regions.  We would like to specify the regions.  For example, if we wanted to just grid the entire map, and then the user clicks on a grid section 
to view all placemarks within that section only.

Since these web developers are more coders than “mappers” I hoped some of you very smart folk might have suggestions. Many thanks in advance

Sara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not correct(when you mean https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html )

A Marker(including the icon....your thumbnail) will not be loaded until it's `map`-property will be set to a `google.maps.Map`-instance.

So when your developers don't set the map-property on their own and let the MarkerClusterer handle the map-property only the Markers(thumbnails) which are not in a cluster and are visible in the viewport(including a small offset) will be loaded.

**Demo:**(creates 500 Markers and  counts 1 time for each marker when the `map`-property changes to the `google.maps.Map` . When you take a look at developer-console->network you'll see that even all these markers/icon will not be loaded completely. For me initially only about 5-10 images will be requested ):

```js
function initialize() {
        var goo         = google.maps,
            map         = new goo.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                                  zoom: 3,
                                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
                                  noClear:true
                          }),
            markers     = [],
            randLatLng  = function(){
                            return new goo.LatLng(((Math.random() * 17000 - 8500)/100),
                                                  ((Math.random() * 36000 - 18000)/100));
                         },
            count       = document.getElementById('count');
        
        map.controls[goo.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(count);
        
        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
          
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: randLatLng(),
            icon: 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_text_small&chld=bbT|'+i+'|FF8|000' 
          });
          (function(m){
            var listener=google.maps.event.addListener(m,'map_changed',function(){
            if(this.getMap()===map){
              count.firstChild.data=parseInt(count.firstChild.data,10)+1
              google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
            }
          });
          }(marker));
          
          markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,body,#map{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
#count{background:tomato;padding:8px;font:bold 1.3em bold Monospace !important}
#count::after{content:' of 500 markers added to map'}
```

```html
<div id="map"><div id="count">0</div></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
    <script src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer_compiled.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Dr Molle!  You've given me hope!  I do truly appreciate you taking the time to explain this.